# I need to create or update existing SharePoint "MODERN VIEW" page layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Try to add 4 custom web parts in a single row, but SharePoint modern view have max 3 col for a row.
[image]

can i edit existing page layout or can i create a new page layout for a 4 col as i want to add 4 web parts in a single row.
[image]

Also let me know if I missed any details or need any clarification.

Comment: It is not recommended to update existing page layouts.

Comment: Yes, i know but is there any way to create a new one. and i have to update it. i have no choice